# Characteristic function verifying a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a r.v. such that $E[X]=0,E[X^2]=\sigma^2,$ suppose that the characteristic function $\varphi$ of $X,$ verifies the following :
$$\varphi\varphi''-(\varphi')^2=-\sigma^2\varphi^2.$$

Prove that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\varphi(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}.$$

Since $\varphi(0)=1,\varphi'(0)=0,$ and on $[-\eta,\eta],\eta>0,$ (since $\varphi$ is continuous at $0$), we have $$\frac{\varphi''}{\varphi}-(\frac{\varphi'}{\varphi})^2=-\sigma^2$$
Solving this equation of $[-\eta,\eta]$ gave $\varphi(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}.$

How to have the result on $\mathbb{R}?$ Is it possible to prove, under the above conditions, that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\varphi(x) \neq0?$

Comment: What is the question? It seems you have solved the problem already?

Comment: You proved that on some neigbourhood of $0$ your $\varphi$ is gaussian. Note that it is an analytic function, thus you can write it as a power series. What is the radius of the series?

Comment: it's not solved, it should be for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: if $\varphi(x) \neq 0,$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ it's over

Comment: If you'd like you can argue as follows. $\varphi$ is uniformly continuous, so given $\varepsilon$ we can find suitable $\delta$ such that... .Assume there is "first" zero on positive axis at point $s > 0$ (that is $\varphi(s) =0$ and $\varphi(t) >0$ for $t \in [0,s)$ ), but then your argument will work on interval $[0,s-\frac{1}{2}\delta]$ where $\delta$ is choosed for $\varepsilon = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}s^2\sigma^2)$. But then $\varphi(s)>0$ (Indeed $\varphi(s-\frac{1}{2}\delta) > \varepsilon = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}s^2\sigma^2)$ ) That is contrary. You can do the same on negative axis

Comment: Another way which I mentioned in the comments about analyticity would be to write $\varphi$ as power series, showing the radius of convergence is $\infty$ and then by uniqueness of power series expansion you would get that formula for $\varphi$ works for any $x \in \mathbb R$. 
More probabilistic argument: Characteristic function for random variable is unique. You can check that $\varphi(x) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2)$ is a characteristic function ($\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variable) and verifies your equation, which by assumption is verified by c.f of $X$.

Comment: Your first argument is impressive, using continuity, to prove that if $\exists \eta>0$ such that $\varphi=e^{-x^2\sigma^2/2},\forall x \in [-\eta,\eta]$ then this is true on $\mathbb{R},$ ($\varphi$ is takes value in $\mathbb{C},$ but we can use $|\varphi|$ instead, for inequality)

Comment: Right, I should used $|\varphi|$ in that inequality